# converting "mmm-yy" to "dd/mm/yyy"

Tags: vba, date, format

Does anyone have any idea how to convert a date formatted "mmm-yy" (in a ComboBox)to "dd/mm/yyyy". I have tried:

```
 Format(Me.ComboBox5.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

But, VBA's interpretation of this causes the month and year to become the day and month and the year is then taken as 2016. For example Mar-12 becomes 12/03/2016.
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: simple: don't let vba GUESS what your input it. parse it properly to a standard datetime object, then format from that.

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing that? Surely, there must be a formatting trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function ChangeDate(strInput As String) As Date


Dim iYear, iMonth    

iYear = CInt(Split(strInput, "-")(1))
iMonth = Month("01/" & Format(Split(strInput, "-")(0), "mmmm"))

ChangeDate= DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1)

End Function
```